# shadow happened when no object declared with the same name in function

Tags: c++, shadow

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int absolute(int);

class Data{
public:
    Data(int);
    ~Data();
    int length();
    int operator[](int);
private:
    int *answer;
    int answerLength;
    void read_data(int*, int);
    void wait();
};

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    Data data = Data(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
        cout << data[i] << " ";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

Data::Data(int one){
    int length = one;
    int *data = new int[length];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        *(data+i) = 100000000;
    }
    thread one(read_data, data, length);
    thread two(wait);
    two.join();
    one.detach();
    one.~thread();
    int smallest = absolute(*(data+1) - *(data+0));
    int smallest_number = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length && *(data+i) != 100000000; i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < length && *(data+j) != 100000000; j++){
            if(absolute(*(data+i) - *(data+j)) < smallest){
                smallest = absolute(*(data+i) - *(data+j));
                smallest_number = 1;
            }else if(absolute(*(data+i) - *(data+j)) == smallest){
                smallest_number ++;
            }
        }
    }
    answerLength = 2 * smallest_number;
    answer = new int[2 * smallest_number];
    int location_one = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length && *(data+i) != 100000000; i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < length && *(data+j) != 100000000; j++){
            if(absolute(*(data+i) - *(data+j)) == smallest){
                *(answer+location_one) = *(data+i);
                location_one ++;
                *(answer+location_one) = *(data+j);
                location_one ++;
            }
        }
    }
}

int Data::operator[](int one){
    if(one < answerLength){
        return *(answer+one);
    }
    return -1;
}

Data::~Data(){
    delete [] answer;
}

int Data::length(){
    return answerLength;
} 
int absolute(int a){
    if(a >= 0){
        return a;
    }else{
        return a * -1;
    }
    return -1;
}

void Data::read_data(int *data, int length){
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        cin >> *(data+i);
    }
}

void Data::wait(){
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
}
```

I got an error message from my compiler:

```
main.cpp:39:12: error: declaration of ‘std::thread one’ shadows a parameter
```

I have no idea why this is happened. I find some imformation on internet.
Shadow a parameter happened when you declare a object with the same name in function.
And i didnt declare something in curly brackets in `Data::read_data` with the same name `data` and `length`.
what happened and how can i fix it?
I use online ide with the following url
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is reasonably self explanatory, you have a parameter of your method named `one` and you have tried declaring a variable with the same name. Choose a different name for your variable.

A general programming technique is to make your variable names as descriptive as possible as this makes your code much more readable and maintainable and also avoids these problems. Assuming you are using an IDE you don't have to type the long names every time as the code completion should fill in the name from the first few characters.